# Deploying a Reactjs project using nodejs14 to Google App Engine Standard Error Code 13

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine

After 6 months of no issues, I now get an error code 13 when trying to deploy a reactjs project using nodejs14 to Google App Engine Standard via gcloud.

I didn't change the package.json or my app.yaml.  It's always worked without an issue for the past 6 months.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Details:

App.yaml (which is the same as the current deployed version from a week ago)

```
runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$
  - url: /.*
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: .*
    script: auto
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
service_account: xxxxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

After reading numerous post with the same issue, some with solutions....

I've tried the following:

Updating my gcloud sdk:

```
gcloud components update
```

My current version is 436.0.0

Updating my app with the following:

```
gcloud config set interactive/hidden true
gcloud app update --service-account [my-app-id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

My deploy script,

```
gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug --log-http
```

Logs (I've xxx my account information:

```
-- body end --
total round trip time (request+response): 0.201 secs
---- response end ----
----------------------
DEBUG: Operation [apps/xxxxxx/operations/0beef610-20f3-4cc8-90cc- 
ca24b58f2215] 
complete. Result: {
    "done": true,
    "error": {
        "code": 13,
        "message": "An internal error occurred."
    },
    "metadata": {
        "@type": 
"type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1",
        "endTime": "2023-06-28T00:59:14.314Z",
        "insertTime": "2023-06-28T00:44:10.265Z",
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion",
        "target": "apps/xxxxxx/services/default/versions/20230627t144405",
        "user": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com"
    },
    "name": "apps/xxxxxxxx/operations/0beef610-20f3-4cc8-90cc-ca24b58f2215"
}
 Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                        

 DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal 

error occurred.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/xxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 987, 
in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   File "/Users/xxxxxx/google-cloud sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 
    807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 127, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 
692, in RunDeploy
    deployer.Deploy(
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 471, in Deploy
    self.api_client.DeployService(new_version.service, 
new_version.id,
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 230, in DeployService return operations_util.WaitForOperation(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 307, in WaitForOperation
    completed_operation = waiter.WaitFor(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", 
line 261, in WaitFor
    operation = PollUntilDone(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", 
line 322, in PollUntilDone
    operation = retryer.RetryOnResult(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 249, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/util/waiter.py", 
line 320, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/operations_util.py", line 182, 
in IsDone
    raise OperationError(requests.ExtractErrorMessage(googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.operations_util.OperationError:Error Response: [13] An 
internal error occurred.
```

Comment: See if this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76240802/15211203) applies to you

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm not sure how I missed that post.  After adding  "gcp-build": "", to my package.json, it worked again.

Comment: Great! I saw your post on Google Cloud Community. You can mark that as answered.