# Nuxt 2 deploying to Google App Engine - Error: Page not found

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, vuejs2, nuxt.js, app.yaml

When using `npm run dev` and `npm run start`, my application runs correctly on the local server. When I use `npm run build` and `npm run generate`, my app builds and generates routes with no errors. I am able to `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` to my google cloud project with no issues. My google app engine versions shows that it is serving on nodejs12. However, when I go to the app link, I am met with 'Error: Page not found The requested URL was not found on this server.'

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs12

instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: /static
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: /static/index.html
    upload: index.html
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
```

In my nuxt.config.js, I have values set to `target: 'static'`,  `pages: 'true'`, and  `ssr: 'false'` .

When running `gcloud app logs tail` I get the error `Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'` .

My npm version is 6.14.6, node js is 12.22.12 and nuxt is 2.17.1.

I'm relatively new to nuxt and I'm using nuxt 2 because there is more documentation here on google app engine deployment. However, I'm facing a lot of issues and everything I try seems to fail. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: See if [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76780873/15211203) helps you